# Deep Sky Objects

Tags: amateur-observing

I have a Meade 114NG Telescope. Last night, I easily saw the beehive cluster (M44) from a light polluted backyard. What other DSOs do you think I should look at and see live in my eyepiece?

Comment: It would be great to include a little information about the telescope so that each reader won't have to look it up for themselves. What's the aperture, focal length and type of optical system for example? Thanks!

Comment: What does DSO stand for?

Comment: My telescope has an aperture if 114mm, Focal length of 1000mm, it is a reflector and my eyepieces are 26 and 9mm.

Comment: DSO = Deep Sky Objects

Answer (score 3):

Some easy deep sky objects you should try,

### Very Easy

- M45
- Omega Centauri
- M13
- Orion Nebula
- M81/82
- M57 (the only planetary nebula you have a chance of seeing from a moderately light polluted sky)
- M6 & M7

### Moderate (requires darker skies)

- M5
- M2
- M8, M17, M18, M20.... (basically the Sagittarius Area and star cloud)
- M31
- M41
- $h$ Persei and $\chi$ Persei

Answer (score 2):

How light polluted are you?

As a general rule, here are the objects that are easiest to see in light polluted skies, in order:

- The Moon
- Bright stars
- Planets
- Globular clusters
- Bright nebulas such as Orion
- Bright galaxies like M-51 or Andromeda

I have successfully imaged most of the Messier catalog objects from a white zone with an 8" telescope.

Forget about faint nebulas.  They'll be washed out in the sky glow.  If you are looking visually, with your scope you should get decent views of Orion.  Many globular clusters should be visible, but in a small scope they will look like faint smudges.  Andromeda should be a decent target as well.

One issue is finding these targets.  Star-hopping is very hard in a very light polluted area, so a goto telescope is a big help.

Comment: Thanks! The telescope I have has an automatic system, and I plan to travel to a dark sky park this summer in northern Michigan. As I am new to astronomy, Will nebulas and bright galaxy’s only look grey, or will color be seen in certain objects. By the way, my telescope is an 114/1000 and I am currently in a white zone.

Comment: You should be able to see color in Orion, and you can see color in the planets and stars, but most deep sky objects will be grey.